# Opencart Displaying min option price

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

What I want to do is perform a query in model which returns all the price of all the options with a specific product id, then in the controller put that into an array and then in the view echo the smallest price, I'm not sure where I am going wrong I know I posted a similiar question but I think this explains it better.

Model

```
public function getMin() {

$queryMin = $this->db->query("SELECT  * FROM  `oc_product_option_value` WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
if (isset($queryMin->row['price'])) {
        return $queryMin->row['price'];
    } else {
        return 0;   
    }

}
```

Controller

```
$minimum = $this->model_catalog_product->getMin();
                $this->data['minimum'] = array();
                foreach ($minimum as $minimums) {
                    $this->data['minimum'][] = array(
                    'price' => $minimum['price']
                    );
                    }
```

View

```
<?php if(isset($this->data['minimum'])){ ?>
    <?php $min = min($this->data['minimum']); ?>
    <?php echo $min ?>
    <?php   }else{ ?>
    <?php   echo $price; ?>
    <?php   } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in Your model method (mostly query).

The `getMin()` method should be:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT MIN(price) min_option_price
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option o ON o.option_id = pov.option_id 
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po ON po.option_id = o.option_id
    WHERE po.product_id = " . (int)$product_id);

return (int) $query->row['min_option_price'];
```

Then in Your controller You get it like this:

```
$minimum = $this->model_catalog_product->getMin($this->request->get['product_id']);
$this->data['minimum'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($minimum, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
```

Now You can use it in Your template directly:

```
<?php if($minimum) { ?>
Minimum price is: <?php echo $minimum; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
Price is: <?php echo $price; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I highly recommend renaming the model's method from `getMin()` to e.g. `getProductOptionMinPrice()`.

Comment: Its currently just returning 1 instead of the price is that just returning that yes there is data in $minimum ?

Comment: No, it should return the minimum price of all the options attached to the product. Check what value is in the `$minimum` variable, maybe it is changed then when formatting.